# Mongoose: can't remove object from array using updateMany

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have several documents in a Mongo collection called Class that have this structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "NpRltypwxkxudbuwcdwx-c-",
    "layout1" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "heading",
            "value" : "Chapter 2"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "set",
            "value" : "dogset"
        },
        {
            "type" : "set",
            "value" : "catset"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update any documents in the collection where the layout1 array includes an object where the value is "dogset" (as an example), such that this object is removed from the layout1 array in all documents that contain it.

After a lot of searching, my best-guess answer is the following (I'm using Nodejs and Mongoose 5.12.8))

```
Class.updateMany(
    {layout1: {$elemMatch: {value: "dogset"}}}, 
    {$pull: {layout1: {$elemMatch: {value: "dogset"}}}}
)
```

I also tried this:

```
Class.updateMany(
    {layout1: {$elemMatch: {value: "dogset"}}}, 
    {$pull: {layout1: {value: "dogset"}}}
)
```

I also tried this:

```
Class.update(
    {layout1: {$elemMatch: {value: "dogset"}}}, 
    {$pull: {layout1: {$elemMatch: {value: "dogset"}}}}, 
    {multi: true}
)
```

These don't generate errors, but the update never happens. Using Mongo version 4.4.1.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: check [this from mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents), i think you need [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DHAyNzPZuul)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the second (middle) option above worked AFTER I added a callback function, which I didn't realize was a requirement. Final code looked like this:

```
Class.updateMany({
   layout1: {$elemMatch: {value: "dogset"}}}, 
   { $pull: { layout1: { value: "dogset"}}}, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
})
```